# Why boot system, load two versions of u-boot?

Tags: mips, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have a gateway device with MT7620a in MIPS architecture. The device has installed OpenWRT. If I connect to device via UART with the goal of flashing new firmware I see something I don't understand, MCU loading two version U-Boot.

- U-Boot **1.1.3**
- Ralink UBoot Version: **4.3.0.0**

Here is **Log System** after start

```
U-Boot 1.1.3 (Apr 27 2015 - 13:54:38)

Board: Ralink APSoC DRAM:  128 MB
relocate_code Pointer at: 87fb8000
enable ephy clock...done. rf reg 29 = 5
SSC disabled.
spi_wait_nsec: 29
spi device id: 1c 70 18 1c 70 (70181c70)
find flash: EN25QH128A
raspi_read: from:30000 len:1000
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

============================================
Ralink UBoot Version: 4.3.0.0
--------------------------------------------
ASIC 7620_MP (Port5<->None)
DRAM component: 1024 Mbits DDR, width 16
DRAM bus: 16 bit
Total memory: 128 MBytes
Flash component: SPI Flash
Date:Apr 27 2015  Time:13:54:38
```

Of course I have a few additional questions in this issue:

1. What is different between these U-Boot ?
2. Why does my device need two versions U-Boot ?
3. Whether this u-boots need separate *.bin image or these is together
   in one image *.bin ? In my device is only one partition for u-boot image and one partition for variables:

   - mtd0: 00030000 00010000 "u-boot"
   - mtd1: 00010000 00010000 "u-boot-env"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexandre Belloni said, there is probably only one version of U-Boot on your device, it just has two different version identifiers.

The reason for this is that manufacturers often need to modify the U-Boot source code in order to get it to operate on their device, or to add features.

On your device, it looks like the version of U-Boot that Ralink pulled from the official U-Boot source code repository is 1.1.3. Ralink's own internal version number that they use for tracking their internal modifications is 4.3.0.0.

Comment: Thank You for reply. I understood reason with identifers two version, and reason with internal number form Ralink, but what does modifi U-Boot to this ? You whant to  me tell that in this moment does not have one stable version which can have one dedicated version ? I little this don't understand.

Comment: @Mbded Sure, they could have one dedicated version identifier, but they chose to keep them separate (which is what I prefer too). They need to keep track of which version of U-Boot they last pulled from somehow, and it's very convenient to have it printed at boot time so anyone can see it. If they wanted to consolidate it to only one version identifier, they'd probably need to maintain an internal document that correlates every version they release to the U-Boot version used. Keep in mind that they probably continue to pull in U-Boot updates over time.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably only one u-boot and "Ralink UBoot Version: 4.3.0.0" is an internal u-boot version for Ralink.

Comment: So U-Boot 1.1.3 is similar to X-Loader as1-st stage boot ? I little not understood Your answer. ..